# Exception occurred in target VM: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Tags: sql, oracle

Can anyone say why it happends?

```
SELECT DISTINCT CMP.CAMPAIGN_NAME,
                CMP.Status,
                ADGRP.Adgroup_Name,
                ADGRP.STATUS,
                AD.STATUS,
                AD.HEADLINE,
                AD.DESCRIPTION1,
                AD.DISPLAY_URL,
                AD.DESTINATION_URL,
                AD.ADCOPY_ID,
                AD.FINAL_URL 3 AS comp_Type,
                ADGRP.ADGROUP_ID AS ADGROUP_ID
  FROM GLE_ADGROUP ADGRP,
       GLE_CAMPAIGN CMP,
       GLE_ADCOPY AD
 WHERE     CMP.ppc_id = 2775
       AND CMP.CAMPAIGN_ID IN ('119471')
       AND CMP.CAMPAIGN_ID = ADGRP.CAMPAIGN_ID
       AND ADGRP.ADGROUP_ID = AD.ADGROUP_ID
       AND CMP.STATUS <> 'Deleted'
       AND ADGRP.STATUS <> 'Deleted'
       AND (    AD.STATUS <> 'Deleted'
            AND AD.STATUS <> 'Disabled')
       AND ad.display_url IS NOT NULL
```

Please help me,
Thanks inadvance.

Comment: in `AD.FINAL_URL 3 as` , what does `3` mean?

Comment: syntax error: 3 as

Comment: If you use a tool, simply trying to format the code will help you to find the problem

Comment: Thank u all... i founf my answer

Answer (score 3):

The problem is probably in this line:

```
            AD.FINAL_URL 3 AS comp_Type,
```

However, you should learn to use proper `JOIN` syntax:

```
 SELECT . . .
 FROM GLE_ADGROUP ADGRP JOIN
      GLE_CAMPAIGN CMP
      ON CMP.CAMPAIGN_ID = ADGRP.CAMPAIGN_ID JOIN
      GLE_ADCOPY AD
      ON ADGRP.ADGROUP_ID = AD.ADGROUP_ID
 WHERE CMP.ppc_id = 2775 AND
       CMP.CAMPAIGN_ID IN ('119471')
       CMP.STATUS <> 'Deleted' AND
       ADGRP.STATUS <> 'Deleted'
       AD.STATUS NOT IN ('Deleted', 'Disabled') AND
       ad.display_url IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thank u ... i founf my answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line: AD.FINAL_URL 3   AS comp_Type,
Probably because there is space between ..URL and 3.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CMP.CAMPAIGN_NAME,
                CMP.Status,
                ADGRP.Adgroup_Name,
                ADGRP.STATUS,
                AD.STATUS,
                AD.HEADLINE,
                AD.DESCRIPTION1,
                AD.DISPLAY_URL,
                AD.DESTINATION_URL,
                AD.ADCOPY_ID,
                /*AD.FINAL_URL */ 3 AS comp_Type,
                ADGRP.ADGROUP_ID AS ADGROUP_ID
  FROM GLE_ADGROUP ADGRP,
       GLE_CAMPAIGN CMP,
       GLE_ADCOPY AD
 WHERE     CMP.ppc_id = 2775
       AND CMP.CAMPAIGN_ID IN ('119471')
       AND CMP.CAMPAIGN_ID = ADGRP.CAMPAIGN_ID
       AND ADGRP.ADGROUP_ID = AD.ADGROUP_ID
       AND CMP.STATUS <> 'Deleted'
       AND ADGRP.STATUS <> 'Deleted'
       AND (    AD.STATUS <> 'Deleted'
            AND AD.STATUS <> 'Disabled')
       AND ad.display_url IS NOT NULL
```